# Reloading DOMContent

Tags: javascript, angular, domcontentloaded

I understand angular is one page application with multiple components and use route to interact between pages.

We have an angular app like that. One of the requirements is that on a specific component we need to add an eventListener to DomContentLoaded event.

Since the index.html page has been loaded (hence DomContentLoaded event has been fired) way before, we have a problem.

I cannot find a way to re-trigger the DomContentLoaded event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DomContentLoaded event fired before the first component was created. You can however use the `ngAfterViewInit()` method.
`ngAfterViewInit()` is a callback method that is invoked immediately after Angular has completed initialization of a component's view. It is invoked only once when the view is instantiated.

```
class YourComponent {
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        // Your code here
    }
}
```

If you really need to catch the DomContentLoaded event anyway, do it in the main.ts file.

Comment: Thanks Marcus... and all others who have answered..
I have to re-trigger DomContentLoaded event because one of the service feed is the script tag and it added the event listern to the DOMContentLoaded event.
I tried to use ngAfterViewIniti() but it doesn't work for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly, why you need to listen to DomContentLoaded in angular, because there are plenty of functions there, depends on which Version of angular do you use.

```
export class SomeComponent implements AfterViewInit {
 ngAfterViewInit(): void {
 }
```

}

But, you can retrigger an rendering of an component with *ngIf (Angular2+) or ng-if (AngularJS). Just put a boolean there and switch the boolean on an event.

Answer (score 0):

Please try not use such listeners, they are (often) not needed in Angular. Try to use [Component lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks).

In your case, I recommend using [ngAfterViewChecked()](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewChecked#ngAfterViewChecked), which fires *when the component finished rendering*.

```js
import { Component, AfterViewChecked } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  ...
})
export class WidgetLgFunnelsComponent implements AfterViewChecked {
  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    console.log('Component finished rendering!')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something with the DOM elements inside the template of the component, and you want to make sure they are there, you should use the [`ngAfterViewInit`](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#afterview) hook from angular:

```
@Component({
  // ...
})
export class SomeComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    // here you can be sure that the template is loaded, and the DOM elements are available
  }
}
```